# $7i(2-5i)$ Opposite sign, why?

Tags: complex-numbers

$7i(2-5i)$ Doing it on my own I got $14i - 35i$. But the answer key says it should be + not - like in the original unsolved part. Why does the sign switch?

Comment: It is $14i+35$, because $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Ohh ok. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Please advise if something remains unclear. If everything ia clear, you might consider answering the question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7i(2-5i) = 7i*2+7i*(-5i)

7i(2) = 14i

7i * (-5i) = -35*i^2
           = -35*(-1) = 35

So, the solution is 14i+35